# Sql bind in Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to use Sql output binding functionalities for Azure function.
Below is my current configuration. I'm using Visual Studio Code as IDE

**Found Python version 3.9.0 (py).

Core Tools Version:       4.0.4736 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)

Function Runtime Version: 4.8.1.18957

Extension bundle version: "[4.*, 5.0.0)"**

functions.json :

```
    {
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "transactions",
      "type": "sql",
      "direction": "out",
      "commandText": "dbo.[table]",
      "connectionStringSetting": "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} etcetc."
    }
  ]
}
```

init.py

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func


def main(
    req: func.HttpRequest, transactions: func.Out[func.SqlRow]
) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info("Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.")

    # i'm using Vue JSON.Stringify({}) in the POST method...on client side
    body = json.loads(req.get_body())
    row = func.SqlRow.from_dict(body)
    transactions.set(row)

    return func.HttpResponse(
        body=json.dumps(body), status_code=201, mimetype="application/json"
    )
```

Error :

```
[2022-09-12T17:49:13.731Z] Executed 'Functions.RegisterNewBatch' (Failed, Id=..., Duration=9ms)
[2022-09-12T17:49:13.732Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:  
 Functions.RegisterNewBatch. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: 
Error while handling parameter _binder after function returned:  
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

Can you please help on that.

Comment: From the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-output?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python) it seems that the  connectionStringSetting isn't the actual connection string and must instead resolve to an environment variable. But still the issue remains on my side ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value for ConnectionString must be included in **local.settings.json** (not env variable).

Answer (score 0):

Check your binding declaration in function.json it should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "todoItems",
    "type": "sql",
    "direction": "out",
    "commandText": "dbo.ToDo",
    "connectionStringSetting": "SqlConnectionString"
}
```

and the ConnectionString in your local.settings.json

```
"SqlConnectionString": "Server={Azure SQL Server};Initial Catalog={Database name};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={user};Password={password};"
```

Here is a full sample for input and output bindings:
https://github.com/DFMERA/azure-functions-sql-binding

Blog Post:
https://acelera.tech/2023/02/10/azure-functions-sql-binding-con-python/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).